# Dart Sdk related problems

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

I ran a Dart program and got this output...
How would I solve it?

```
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.0.5.

Because <application> depends on flutter_icons >=0.0.2 which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
```

Comment: flutter_icons is a very old package that has not been migrated to work with null-safety features. You can see "Dart 3 incompatible" in the pub.dev page for this package. I would recommend using different icon packages

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.